# Suggestions on how to pragmatically allow one Laravel user to add another

Tags: laravel

I need on my Laravel set-up (which uses the standard Auth models/controller) to allow a logged-in user to create another user account on the site.  As a shot in the dark, on my "add user" page, I did an include of the form from auth.register, and it showed up fine on the page (great!), but when I filled out the form and submitted it, it just reloaded the page, with no errors and the new user was not added to the database.

The things I'd need different than the standard auth.register are

1) There will be a column in the `users` table pairing the two users.

2) I want the verification email to be different than if they signed up on their own.

3) I was also thinking to not let the creating user choose a password, but have the new user reset their password via the initial email.

Is there any Laravel way of doing all this or will I have to write it myself?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) There will be a column in the users table pairing the two users.

Take a look in your RegisterController and check out the `use RegisterUsers` trait included. Whatever you copy from this trait and move it to RegisterController, it gets overwritten by your logic rather than trait logic.

For the pairing, you can utilise `create()` method. A really pseudo way:

```
protected function create(array $data) {
    $pair = // find a random user

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'pair_id' => $pair->id
    ]);
}
```

> 2) I want the verification email to be different than if they signed up on their own.

For this, I am not sure where you trigger it already, but the email event lives in EventServiceProvider by default:

```
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ]
];
```

Change it your custom email and you should be good.

> 3) I was also thinking to not let the creating user choose a password, but have the new user reset their password via the initial email.

Again, in `create()` method, you can just assign a random password, and with your email, redirect them to the ResetPassword actions somehow. This needs some time to figure out for me now but see reset-password routes (with `php artisan route:list`), so what it accepts and in your custom email, place the button with necessary link.

Make sure you don't login the user right after registering in that case.

So, bottomline - the auth default logics live in their traits, and if you want to overwrite some, just copy/paste the method to your controller and tweak it as you wish.

Comment: Right now I'm just using the standard Laravel Auth for registration.  I was kind of surprised that it does nothing when put on a "new" registration page and is submitted.  My first step is to figure out why that's not working (I should have been more clear in my question) and then work on the things I need it to do differently from there.

Comment: if you are using `Auth::routes()` approach, then `php artisan route:list` is your friend. Try to see which controller methods it's getting pointed at and you'll be able to customize your needs

Comment: From the route list it says that it's being handled with `RegisterController@register`, though there's no `register` function in RegisterController.php.  I think I may have found it in a ServiceProvider, but that's over my head.  I did figure out that the reason the form submission wasn't working was because of:

`$this->middleware('guest');`
    
in RegisterController.php.  If I comment it out, it submits as expected.  Though it's needed for regular sign-ups.  So I have to figure out how to change it to `$this->middleware('auth');` if it's coming from my "add user" page.

Comment: _"though there's no register function in RegisterController.php"_ - It comes from the trait `use RegisterUsers` which is included in RegisterController.php. As I said, copy your desired method from that trait and paste inside your RegisterController which let's you overwrite as desired.